# Golang: package setup to orchestrate initialization

Tags: go

The following code implements a package, which can be used to execute functions in the correct order based on dependencies.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "my/setup"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // a depends on nothing
    a := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("a") })
    // b depends on a
    b := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("b") }, a)
    // c depends on b
    c := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("c") }, b)
    // d depends on a
    d := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("d") }, a)
    _, _ = c, d
    setup.Exec()
    // Prints: a, b, d, c
}
```

Is there anything I can improve?

```golang
// Orchestrates the execution of initialization functions with
// dependencies.
package setup

import (
    "sort"
)

// Anything that can be done during the initalization.
type Func func()
type Action *Func
type sequence_t func() int
type sernos_t map[Action]int
type ranks_t map[Action]int
type actions_t []Action
type dependencies_t map[Action][]Action

// A list of actions and their dependencies.
type setup_t struct {
    sequence     sequence_t
    sernos       sernos_t
    dependencies dependencies_t
}

var setup *setup_t = new(setup_t)

// Create a new Setup
func init() {
    i := -1
    setup.sequence = func() int { i = i + 1; return i }
    setup.sernos = make(sernos_t)
    setup.dependencies = make(dependencies_t)
}

// Add an action with optional dependencies to the setup.  Adding is
// not thread safe.
func Add(init Func, dependencies ...Action) Action {
    action := &init
    setup.sernos[action] = setup.sequence()
    setup.dependencies[action] = dependencies
    return action
}

// Execute all actions in the right row, considering their dependenciesetup.
func Exec() {
    ranks := make(ranks_t)
    // Calculate the rank of an action and memoize the result in
    // ranksetup.  The rank of an action is one more than the maximum of
    // the ranks of all dependenciesetup.  The rank of an action defines the
    // execution order during the setup.
    var rank func(Action)
    rank = func(action Action) {
        if len(setup.dependencies[action]) == 0 {
            ranks[action] = 0
        }
        max := 0
        for _, dependency := range setup.dependencies[action] {
            rank(dependency)
            if ranks[dependency] > max {
                max = ranks[dependency]
            }
        }
        ranks[action] = max + 1
    }
    // Create a list of all actions and calculate the rank of every
    // action.
    actions := make(actions_t, len(setup.sernos))
    i := 0
    for action := range setup.sernos {
        actions[i] = action
        i = i + 1
        _, ok := ranks[action]
        if !ok {
            rank(action)
        }
    }
    // Sort the actions first by rank and second by serno.
    sort.Slice(actions, func(i, j int) bool {
        ai := actions[i]
        aj := actions[j]
        if ranks[ai] == ranks[aj] {
            return setup.sernos[ai] < setup.sernos[aj]
        }
        return ranks[ai] < ranks[aj]
    })
    // Execute the actions in order.
    for i := range actions {
        (*actions[i])()
    }
    // Allow setup only once.
    setup = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Action` as a map key seems dubious. As I understand it, a pointer to a function can only be compared to `nil`, not other function pointers, so I'm not sure how this would work with a map. I'd be very interested to see some unit tests showing this working as expected if you have some time.

Addressing the code shown, this could potentially be a lot simpler, but I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to accomplish with ranking. Custom types like you have defined (not type *aliases*) can have methods, so you can attach a method to any given `Func` and use it to chain multiple `Func` together.

```golang
// Given the Func type you have defined in your code.
func (f Func) Then(others ...Func) Func {
    // func() is implicitly cast to Func.
    // This cast works with return values and parameters.
    return func() {
        f()
        // Call all other Func, if any.
        for _, other := range others {
            other()
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Including a `DependsOn` method to `Func` for "happens before" type relationships.

```golang
func (f Func) DependsOn(dependencies ...Func) Func {
    return func() {
        // Call all other Func, if any.
        for _, other := range others {
            other()
        }
        f()
    }
}
```

You could use this pattern to add things before or after a Func executes to construct whatever logic your heart desires. Since Func is really a function under the hood, you can just call it with all of its embedded functions, and they'll all execute in the order specified.

Also, it looks like you might be coming from a C background (guessing from the *_t). In Go, we really try to avoid global state. This could potentially be done using a constructor function and methods for `setup_t`.

```golang
// A list of actions and their dependencies.
type setup_t struct {
    sequence     sequence_t
    sernos       sernos_t
    dependencies dependencies_t
}

// No longer needed! :)
// var setup *setup_t = new(setup_t)

// NewSetup allows constructing and initializing a setup_t.
func NewSetup() *setup_t {
    i := -1
    setup.sequence = func() int { i = i + 1; return i }
    setup.sernos = make(sernos_t)
    setup.dependencies = make(dependencies_t)
}

// Using 'setup' as the method receiver means you wouldn't have to change any
// code inside these methods, and you wouldn't be referencing global state.
// After this, you could refactor to make the receiver more idiomatic.

func (setup *setup_t) Add(init Func, dependencies ...Action) Action {
    /* ... */
}

func (setup *setup_t) Exec() {
    /* ... */
}
```

This change could make your main code look something like this.

```golang
func main() {
    // Alternative using only Func with Then chaining.
    abcd := setup.Func(func(){fmt.Println("a")}).
        // Showing multiple Funcs in Then.
        Then(func(){fmt.Println("b")}, func(){fmt.Println("c")}).
        Then(func(){fmt.Println("d")})
    abcd()
    // Prints: a, b, c, d

    // EDIT: Using DependsOn, with underscore identifiers to prevent issues later in the code.
    // The receiver type is still a function, and these methods produce a closure that calls parameters, so there's no issue with the receiver being singular.
    _a := setup.Func(func() {fmt.Println("a")})
    _b := setup.Func(func() {fmt.Println("b")})
    _c := setup.Func(func() {fmt.Println("c")})
    _d := setup.Func(func() {fmt.Println("d")})
    abdc := _d.DependsOn(_a, _b).Then(_c)
    abdc()
    // Prints: a, b, d, c

    // Intentionally shadowing the 'setup' package name here.
    // Everything below this can remain the same with this shadowing.
    // I'd recommend changing this name with a refactor though.
    setup := setup.NewSetup()
    // a depends on nothing
    a := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("a") })
    // b depends on a
    b := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("b") }, a)
    // c depends on b
    c := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("c") }, b)
    // d depends on a
    d := setup.Add(func() { fmt.Println("d") }, a)
    _, _ = c, d
    setup.Exec()
    // Prints: a, b, d, c
}
```

A practical example of setting up function method chaining can be seen [here](https://github.com/saylorsolutions/modmake/blob/main/task.go#L68-L85).

```golang
// Task is a convenient way to make a function that satisfies the Runner interface, and allows for more flexible invocation options.
type Task func(ctx context.Context) error

/* ... */

func (t Task) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    return t(ctx)
}

/* ... */

func (t Task) Then(other Runner) Task {
    return func(ctx context.Context) error {
        if err := t(ctx); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return other.Run(ctx)
    }
}

// Catch runs the catch function if this Task returns an error.
func (t Task) Catch(catch func(error) error) Task {
    return func(ctx context.Context) error {
        if err := t(ctx); err != nil {
            return catch(err)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The dependencies are a list. A receiver is just one.

Comment: @ceving If I understand what you mean, the suggested code should support that. Since `others` is a vararg, you could pass multiple `Func` in a `Then` call.

Comment: @ceving I'm not sure what you mean by "A receiver is just one." Could you elaborate?

Comment: "receiver" is typical the name for the object/struct to which the method is attached. In Java it is called `this`, in Go it does not have a dedicated name. You call it `t` in `Then`. I think your code has reversed the logic of my code. If you call a method `Then` of the struct A and pass B and C  this probably means: first A and after that B and C. And this probably means B has the dependency A and C has the dependency A. So every task can depend on exactly one other task. What I tried to implement is: every task can depend on more than one other task.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, @ceving. You could reverse the execution order in `Then` (and probably call it something like `DependsOn` for clarity) and pass dependencies if that's what you'd prefer. Basically just move the `f()` call to after the for loop. Either way, you can order function calls however you'd like with this method, with arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: I'll update the answer to include this possibility.